# Anyone know about TortoiseHg error : "abort: default repository not configured!"?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Everytime I do a `commit`, I get ....

> abort: default repository not configured! hint: see the path section
>   in the "hg help config"
>
> [Code 255]

.. so I type `hg help config` and it apparently doesn't really have a "path" section. It does have a file section which talks about config files, saying...

```
On Windows, the following files are consulted:
- "<repo>/.hg/hgrc" (per-repository)
- "%USERPROFILE%\.hgrc" (per-user)
- "%USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini" (per-user)
- "%HOME%\.hgrc" (per-user)
- "%HOME%\Mercurial.ini" (per-user)
- "<install-dir>\Mercurial.ini" (per-installation)
- "<install-dir>\hgrc.d\*.rc" (per-installation)
- "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial" (per-installation)
- "<internal>/default.d/*.rc" (defaults)
```

...So I look in my `/.hg/hgrc` file, and I see:

`[paths] default = M:\Workspaces\AziGamma`  which is my parent folder path.

I'm still not clear how I'm supposed to address this error. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As `hg help config` says:

> "default"
>
> Directory or URL to use when pulling if no source is specified.
>   Default is set to repository from which the current repository was
>   cloned.

That means you should have original repository in `M:\Workspaces\AziGamma` and it is not there, hence the error you receive.

How to solve the error:

1. If you have cloned repository from `M:\Workspaces\AziGamma` then make sure that original master repository is still in that path. If you have moved it, replace path in `hgrc` file with new location.
2. If you haven't cloned your repository and you don't have any original master repository (or you cloned but you don't need it anymore) - which means that you are not going to `push/pull` - then just delete line `default = M:\Workspaces\AziGamma` from your `hgrc` file